# Is there an R equivalent of Python's '*'?

Tags: r

In python you can do:

```
val = [1, 2, 3]

def f(a, b, c):
    return(a+b+c)

f(*val)

>>>6
```

But is there an R equivalent to passing a list/vector to a function and having it unpack the list/vector as the arguments to the function?

```
val <- c(1, 2, 3)
f <- function(a, 
              b, 
              c) {
     a+b+c
     }
#f(*val)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Base R

**do.call** In R it is `do.call`.  The first argument is the function or a character string giving the name of the function and the second argument is a list whose components will be passed as individual arguments to the function.  No packages are used.

```
val <- c(1, 2, 3)
f <- function(a, b, c) a+b+c
do.call("f", as.list(val))
## [1] 6
```

**Reduce** Another approach is to curry `f` creating a new function with the first argument fixed, repeatedly doing so using `Reduce` to handle each successive argument.  No packages are used.

```
Reduce(function(f, x, ...) function(...) f(x, ...), val, init = f)()
## [1] 6
```

### purrr package

**invoke** The purrr package has `invoke` which basically just calls `do.call` but it will also convert the second argument to a list if it is not already a list:

```
library(purrr)
invoke(f, val)
## [1] 6
```

**lift** purrr also has `lift` which will convert a function that takes individual arguments to a new function that takes a list or vector. It also wraps `do.call`

```
lift(f)(val)
## [1] 6
```

**partial** purrr also has `partial` which will curry the function creating a new function with the first argument fixed taking only the remaining arguments so using `reduce` (also in purrr) to repeatedly invoke such currying:

```
reduce(val, partial, .init = f)()
## [1] 6
```

### functional package

**Curry** `Curry` from the functional package could also be used to fix the first argument.  When used together with `Reduce` from base R to repeatedly apply `Curry` it gives the same result.  Note that `Curry` uses `do.call` internally.

```
library(functional)
Reduce(Curry, init = f, val)()
## [1] 6
```

Comment: FYI `invoke` is retired now, I suppose it will keep working for a long time, but the recommended usage is now `exec(f, !!!val)`. The `!!!` notation is supported natively by many functions of the tidyverse packages and is then the closes thing to the python idiom, though in these cases it only works in the `...` argument.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to [lift the domain of a function](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/lift.html) using `lift()` from the `purrr` package. Your definition of `f` takes multiple arguments, which in R terms is known as "dots". You can change its signature to accept a vector instead:

```
f2 <- purrr::lift_dv(f)
f2(val)
## [1] 6

# Or as a one-liner
purrr::lift_dv(f)(val)
```